# how to handle long time idle frame

Tags: frame

I’m encountering an issue during file upload. After selecting the file to be uploaded, I noticed a long idle frame of about 20 seconds in the Chrome Developer Tools. This issue only occurs on the first page load, and subsequent file uploads work normally. I’m unsure what could be causing this. Could anyone help analyze this issue?
[chrome dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5idx.png)

I’ve tried using the Performance tool to analyze if there are any tasks that take a long time to complete, but I haven’t made any progress.